# R : Subscript out of Bond using arule

Tags: r, bounds, arules

I'm using arules packages, and looking for rules I have this problem:

NB: txn is my transactions matrix

You can download here my CSV

[My CVS File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xBfa1Z3jRtBXHcOJc1Aat0vG2bpnt9K_/view?usp=sharing)

## convert csv file to basket format

```
library(arules)

txn = read.transactions(file="ItemList.csv", rm.duplicates= FALSE, format="basket",sep=",",cols=1);
```

## remove quotes from transactions

```
txn@itemInfo$labels <- gsub("\"","",txn@itemInfo$labels)

rules <- apriori(txn,
                 parameter = list(support=.001,
                                  confidence=.5,
                                  minlen=2,
                                  target='rules' # to mine for rules
                 ))
>summary(rules)

... etc

> inspect(sort(rules, by='lift', decreasing = T)[1:5])
Error in slot(x, s)[i] : subscript out of bounds
```

At the end, My error is

Error in slot(x, s)[i] : subscript out of bounds

I read online that my problem should not come from a "wrong code" but from R settings.
Thank you all for your help!

Comment: In general, with weird errors the first thing to do is `options(error = recover)` and use the debugger. See `?recover`.

Comment: Also, please make a [mcve] using `dput`. Then people can help you by running your code to debug it. Thx and welcome to SO!

Comment: Ok, I'll do as you suggested me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved. Setting Support=0.00001 in rules makes everything work

```
rules <- apriori(txn,
                 parameter = list(support=.00001,
                                  confidence=.5,
                                  minlen=2,
                                  target='rules' # to mine for rules
                 ))
```